# UPDATE sql query from two table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables with values stored as below.

**Table1**

```
ReferranceID   StatusNumber   ServiceType            T2OpenDt          T1OpenDT
162987          399519        Orthopaedic Surgery       NULL           2011-08-19 
162987          399525        Acupuncture               NULL           2011-08-19 
162987          413405        Anesthesiology            NULL           2011-09-28 
162987          517174        Chiropractic              NULL           2012-04-26
```

**Table2**

```
ReferranceID StatusNumber   Status     T2OpenDate
162987       256033         Closed     2010-11-17 
162987       488518         ReOpen     2012-02-22
```

The first table should be updated as below from the 2nd table. (i.e the Result values)

```
ReferranceID   StatusNumber   ServiceType               T2OpenDt          T1OpenDT
162987          399519        Orthopaedic Surgery       2010-11-17         2011-08-19 
162987          399525        Acupuncture               2010-11-17         2011-08-19 
162987          413405        Anesthesiology            2010-11-17         2011-09-28 
162987          517174        Chiropractic              2012-02-22         2012-04-26
```

**'2010-11-17'** will be updated in **3 rows** since the T2OpenDate is less than T1Opendate and
there is only one occurance of **2012-02-22** since this date is slightly greater than other 3 top T1OpenDate and less than the 4th T1OpenDate.

Could anybody suggest me the UPDATE sqlquery for the above.  Thank you so very much for helping me.

Comment: What if there are other rows in table2 for the same referral? E.g. the status has been closed and re-opened multiple times?

Comment: There can be any number of status like (closed/open/reopen). We have to pick the max of the date which should be less than the T1OpenDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET T2OpenDate = (SELECT MAX(Table2.T2OpenDate)
                      FROM Table2 
                      WHERE Table2.T2OpenDate < Table1.T1OpenDate)                       
FROM Table1
```

**EDITED** according to Aaron Bertrand's commnet.

If you want to get better on this particular skill I suggest you read this: [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select/2334741#2334741)

Comment: This doesn't give the right answer for the 4th row. You can fix this by adding `DESC` to the `ORDER BY` or removing that and changing `TOP 1` to `MAX`.

Comment: Thanks Daniloquio.  I tried your query and as suggest by Aaron Bertrand i have added order by 'DESC' in the script, the result is accurate what i wanted.
Thanks so very much for the quick solution you have provided.

Comment: I slightly modified the above script to get the actual values after testing.
UPDATE T1     
  SET T2OpenDate  = 
  (SELECT TOP 1 Table2.T2OpenDate                        
   FROM Table2                        
   WHERE Table2.T2OpenDate < T1.T1OpenDT  ORDER BY Table2.T2OpenDate desc)
 FROM Table1  T1

Comment: @desi my pleasure ... and thanks to you because this is my 1000 points answer, finally I'm a stackoverflow stablished user :)